any known issue upgrading an existing sb2.7/jdk11/db2 application that uses eclipselink to sb3.2.4 / jdk17 /eclipselink v4.0.2?
after upgrading an existing application (springboot 2.7.x / jdk11 / db2 / eclipselink) to springboot 3.2.4 and jdk17 (and eclipselink to v4.0.2)  the application compiles and starts up...  but is now getting the following error:
--UnitOfWork(35385854)
--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction.
Attempting to retry query.
Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectRecoverableException: [jcc][t4][2034][11148][4.33.31]
Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation.
A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected. Reason: 0x1. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009 

...log when displaying the associated "select" shows hundreds of "?".
e.g.,
select colvalue1 from table1 where (colvalue2 in (????????????????.....)
Question:  is this a known issue with such an upgrade?
thx for any help/guidance
